# How to undo Nginx config?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

This is so bizzare. I have nginx configured to listen on both port 80 and 443. I only want SSL on 443 but non-SSL was showing Nginx default page. I found a solution to redirect port 80 traffic to 443 like this:

`return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

It seemed to work but after testing my site I noticed all requests on all routes were redirecting to my homepage. I have since removed the above configuration but it still persists.

I have not edited the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Here is my current configuration. How do I undo this? Thanks in advance

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    ### << this is where I had the above redirect line >> ###
    # SSL configuration
            listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /path/to//cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite**

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /var/www/example.com;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, how do I achieve/enforce connection to SSL/https only?

Comment: Have you restarted the Nginx since you revert the change?

Comment: Yes. I’ve tried to stop/start/enable/restart

Comment: Is this happens all the time or just when you try the IP address instead of the URL?

Comment: works fine with IP

Comment: Are you using Chrome by chance? As it has a nasty habit of forcing all request to HTTPS by default.

Comment: Also, do you make a symbolic to `sites-enabled` from `sites-available`or copy the file to `sites-enabled` from `sites-available`?

Comment: yes. It was chrome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, There's a way to force it not to do that for selected domains. But don't remember where exactly. But I do know its one of the links in here. chrome://chrome-urls/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188968/discussion-between-dweeb-and-praveen-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close to having it working; only you added the redirection on the **default** configuration file. This is a bad idea because it sometimes can have bad side effects like you experience now.

in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite` can have more than one `server{}` block.

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually have changed my config to that, however I can’t get the original change to undo. I’ll try another browser as I am using chrome.